# SaaS-company structure

Tags: saas

What is the most typical structure of business where you want to develop several web services? Should one establish a company for each of them or keep under one? I would like to hear your experiences maintaining such situation, keeping in mind the global focus.

Comment: this belongs on startups or somewhere other than here.

Answer (score 1):

By far the two most critical sets of issues determining the answer to this question are legal and financial (including, but not mainly, accounting). So it's hard to see how this question fits with the intent of this site.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to provide more background information on the topic. Business plans for SaaS companies can range from large cloud computing service vendors (with integrated solutions) and up to business analytics providers targeting specific market niche.

Answer (score 0):

Business is a bit like programming: Keep It Simple (Stupid). Do not create multiple companies, unless there is a good reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If You Planning to use python, you can use Django to build saas application,

this video [Build SaaS application in Python django](https://youtu.be/jg4qs9Qs6Fs) will explain about getting started with Sass.

Thanks